# Natural Language to Formal Propositional Logic, "get neither"

Tags: predicate-logic

I've been working through a few translations and I found one I am not too sure as to the formatting of.

I believe the first part is right but in the second part where it says he will get neither, I am unsure if the correct format is to negate both symbols, or if there is another way?

The sentence is:

**Johnny wants both a train and a bike for Christmas but he will get neither.**

This is my current attempt of translation:

**Jt = Johnny wants a train**

**Jb = Johnny wants a bike**

> $$(Jt\land Jb) \land \lnot(Jt \lor Jb)$$

Thank you

Comment: observe that $\lnot (Jt\lor Jb)\iff \lnot Jt\land \lnot Jb$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't work. Your sentence ends up saying:

**Johnny wants both a train and a bike for Christmas but he $\color{red}{wants}$ neither.**

You'll need to add some sentence variables that symbolize Johnny **getting** a train or bike.

So, say you have:

**Wt = Johnny wants a train**

**Wb = Johnny wants a bike**

**Gt = Johnny gets a train**

**Gb = Johnny gets a bike**

Then you can do:

$(Wt \land Wb) \land \neg (Gt \lor Gb)$

So: your *idea* was certainly correct ... but you just needed some additional sentences to capture the **getting** part

Comment: Ahh okay, so by adding lets say two variables Gt and Gb and replacing them for the last two, that should do the trick?

Comment: typed this before you made the edit^ thank you for your response!

Comment: @BenConlon Yup!  And like I said, otherwise you totally had the right idea!